# Array key naming when class is casted to an array

Tags: php

When I cast a class to an array, the keys are named differently depending on which accessor the class property has.

Public properties always has the same key as the property name, but private properties are prepended with an `X` and protected properties with a `*`.

I was looking for a reference in the PHP documentation for this behaviour, but failed to find any. I have replicated this in both PHP 5.6 and 7.1.

Why does this happen? Is this documented somewhere?

#### Code

```
<?php

class X {
  private $a = 1;
  protected $b = 2;
  public $c = 3;
}

$class = new X();

var_dump((array) $class);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  ["Xa"]=>
  int(1)
  ["*b"]=>
  int(2)
  ["c"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the manual [Click here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side. This can result in some unexpected behaviour: